# Calculating the sum of $\sum\frac{n^2-2}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Calculating the sum of $\sum\frac{n^2-2}{n!}$

I want to calculate the sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2-2}{n!}$.

This is what I have done so far:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2-2}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}-2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}-2e$$

And here I don't know how to deal with the $\frac{n}{(n-1)!} $. Any tips?

EDIT:
One of the answers recommends to write down the sum as follows:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2-2}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n(n-1)}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{n!}-2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$

Which equals to:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n(n-1)}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{n!}-2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(n-1)}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!} -2e$$

But here I have negative factorials. What should I do next? Or can I just say that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}=e$?

Comment: To avoid problems like $(-1)!$, it seems better to begin the sum at $n=1$:$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {n^2}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{n!}$$

Comment: Once you know what is $\sum\frac{1}{n!}$, this is essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/44113/9464).

Comment: And also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/679790/9464), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1242818/9464).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that can be applied to a wide class of problems.**

---

The Taylor series representation of he exponential function is given by

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}} \tag 1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ term-by-term, we see that

$$\frac{d\,e^x}{dx}=e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n x^{n-1}}{n!} \tag2$$

whereby multiplying $(2)$ by $x$ reveals

$$xe^x =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n!} \tag 3$$

---

Differentiating $(3)$, multiplying by $x$, and subtracting $2e^x$, we obtain

$$(x^2+x-2)e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n^2-2)\,x^{n}}{n!} \tag 4$$

Finally, setting $x=1$ in $(4)$ yields

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=0}\frac{n^2-2}{n!}=0}$$

and we are done!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Write
$$
\frac{n^2-2}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}+\frac{n}{n!}-\frac2{n!}
$$

---

Note that by throwing out terms which are zero,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n!}
$$

Comment: You guys are something else, how am I supposed to compete with this!?  XD  Good answer, +1

Comment: @robjohn I edited the answer, could you take a look?

Comment: @user401855: I have added a couple of "notes".

Comment: So basically the sum is $0$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242818/exploring-sum-n-0-infty-fracnpn-b-pe-particularly-p-2), we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^p}{n!}=B_pe$$

where $B_n$ is the $n$th Bell number.

Comment: A link to [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Bell_numbers) might be helpful, too.

Comment: I just realized that I had posted [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1520778/13854), which is closely related to your answer.

Comment: @robjohn Nice find man

Answer (score 0):

Adjust indices so that you have $\frac {n+1}{n!}$ and separate that out into $\frac n{n!}+\frac1{n!}$.