# How to show $\frac{2}{2!}+\frac{7}{3!}+...+\frac{k^2-2}{k!}+...+\frac{9998}{100!}<3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, telescopic-series

Demonstrate the inequality$$\frac{2}{2!}+\frac{7}{3!}+...+\frac{k^2-2}{k!}+...+\frac{9998}{100!}<3$$

**Attempt**:

$$\sum^{100}_{n=2} \frac{n^2-2}{n!}$$

Note that $n^2-2 \leq n^2$, so we have:

$$\sum^{100}_{n=2} \frac{n^2-2}{n!} \leq \sum^{100 }_{n=2}\frac{n^2}{n !}=\sum^{100}_{n=2}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$$

I would like to solve the problem in a more elementary way, without using a calculator. I thought this problem might have some application to the Bernoulli Inequality, but I have no idea.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $3-\sum_{n=2}^{100}\frac{n^2-2}{n!}\approx10^{-156}$?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of but essentially answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073559/calculating-the-sum-of-sum-fracn2-2n.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\sum^{k}_{n=2} \frac{n^2-2}{n!}&=\sum^{k}_{n=2} \frac{n^2-n}{n!}+\frac{n-2}{n!}\\
\\
&=\sum^{k}_{n=2} \frac{1}{(n-2)!}-\frac{1}{n!}+\sum^{k}_{n=2} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}\\
\\
&=1+1-\frac{1}{(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{k!}+1-\frac{1}{k!}\\
\\
&=3-\frac{1}{(k-1)!}-\frac{2}{k!}\\
\\
&<3\end{align}$$

Comment: (Minor point) The fraction split / telescoping could be written better. EG You're actually going from $(n^2 - n -1 ) / n!  = 1/(n-2)! - 1/n!$.